# PHP MySQL Query insert Function

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any possibilty to add a function-call in a SQL-Query?

At the moment i'm doing this:

```
§sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
```

But I want, that I'm using a field from my table and call with this a function, which return me true or false.

Maybe a example could explain it better:

```
"$sql = SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE functionCall(TABLE.FIELD)=true";
```

Then I just get all entrys from TABLE, where my function returns true.

Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: Read MySQL manuals for built-in functions. I think you can do your task with them

Comment: in addition: you can write [stored functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-views.html), those will work too. But you can't refer to a php function ...

Comment: Can you explain what you would like the functionCall to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use If condition before  like that :

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";

 fetch your query here 

 If(functionCall($row['FIELD'])==true) {
    your wished code here
    .......
  }
```